# how to call multiple function in action?

Tags: ajax, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing a problem while calling multiple functions through AJAX. What i mainly have to do is to call the different functions through AJAX. 
This should be working such that when i try to call those functions, they should be sent a request and the response should be the returned values of those function, but i am getting the error while doing so. Can anyone suggest me how to make it work?

```
public virtual IQueryable<CardViewModel> ChannelQuery(PageInfo p)
    {
        var q = from client in my.Clients(0, 0)
                join m in db.Channels on client.ClientId equals m.ClientId
                join c in db.Contents on m.ChannelId equals c.ContentId
                where c.ContentName.Contains(p.Where) ||                  m.ChannelShortDescription.Contains(p.Where) || m.ChannelName.Contains(p.Where)
                select new CardViewModel
                {
                    Name = "Channel",
                    ID = m.ChannelId,
                    Title = m.ChannelName,
                    Description = m.ChannelShortDescription,
                    Pic = new VZDev.ViewModels.Pic { width = 255, height = 170, source = `enter code here`m.ChannelLogo, text = m.ChannelName },
                    PictureViewTemplate = "_PicBanner",
                    ShowTools = true
                };
        return q;
    }
    public virtual IQueryable<CardViewModel> ContentsQueries(PageInfo p)
    {
        var query = from content in db.Contents
                    join clients in my.Clients(0, 0) on content.ClientId equals clients.ClientId
                    join m in db.Channels on clients.ClientId equals m.ClientId
                    where content.ContentName.Contains(p.Where) || `enter code here`m.ChannelShortDescription.Contains(p.Where) || m.ChannelName.Contains(p.Where)
                    select new CardViewModel
                    {
                        Name = "Content",
                        ID = content.ContentId,
                        Title = content.ContentName,
                        Description = clients.ResellerName,
                        Pic = new VZDev.ViewModels.Pic { width = 255, height = 170, source = `enter code here`"None", text = content.ContentName },
                        PictureViewTemplate = "_PicBanner",
                        ShowTools = true
                    };
        return query;

    }

    public ViewResult Advance(PageInfo p)
    {
        return View(ChannelQuery(p).ToPagedResult(p, "ID Desc"));
    }
```

Comment: can you show your ajax call ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only call one function per AJAX call. If you need Channel and Content data in one request, make a dictionary to hold both sets of values. Something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,object> data = new Dictionary<string,object>();
data.Add("Channel", ChannelQuery());
data.Add("Content", ContentsQuery());
```

Comment: How to call number of function in return view()?

Comment: As i have call one function ChannelQuery(p).I want to call number of function in return view which is given below.
Coding:-


 
        return View(ChannelQuery(p).ToPagedResult(p, "ID Desc"));

Comment: If you're using AJAX, why don't you use Web API?